# UITableViewCell textLabel width size error Expression is not assignable

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, textlabel

I would like to set the frame width of my UITableViewCell label inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` how ever I am receiving an error.

this is how I am trying to set the cell up.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        [cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
        cell.textLabel.frame.size.width = 200.0; // just as an example.
        [cell.textLabel setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
        [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
        [cell.textLabel setTag:1];

        [[cell contentView] addSubview:cell.textLabel];
    }
```

but on the line where I try to set `textLabel.frame.size.width` I get this error

**Expression is not assignable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is self explainable as you can not change `width` and `height` property for the `UITableViewcell`.And more importantly, you can not change the frame of `textLabel` in `UITableViewCell`. You should customize the `UITableViewCell` class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, if you want to do this then it will not give any error but it will not affect on you code.....So just make simple label and then set frame of it then add it to your cell.

```
[cell addSubview:YourLbl];
```